# Why can't I create a hard link?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage

I wanted to  create a hardlink but I  can't. I'm rooted and I want to offload my internal memory  and move the dalvik-cache to my sd-card.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create hard links across file systems, only soft links.

Comment: No. There's not an option in default and I have also tried to link it to cache partition.

Comment: Do you have any reference to back this up?

Comment: What do you mean?  Does this mean across Filesystem means also partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can only hardlink inside the same partition/filesystem. It might help if you [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48305/edit) your question and include the steps you took (i.e. the commands you tried to execute). But from the phrasing it's quite clear you want to re-locate e.g. `/data/dalvik-cache` (located on the `/data` partition) to your SDCard (complete different medium). This cannot be done with hard-links.

I'd recomment you take a look at [Root # All Data2SD card.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rappsd.v1), [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), and [S2E](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e), which help you to offload a bunch of things. For more details, please also refer to our [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), which gives you a short description on all these methods.

Comment: Yes that what I  think.  But question seems clear to me?  I know app2sd and link2sd but it doesn't move the dalvik-cache.

Comment: OK, read it again -- there was a third app :) But admitted: S2E says it works with CM only. One more chance: [Mounts2SD - All-in-one SD-Ext](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.mounts2sd), forgot to mention that. Oh, and of course there's [Directory Bind](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410262).