# Creating a symlink (symbolic link) to files

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, file-system

I'm looking for a way to create a symlink with Android. I know I can write a  script but I don't want to spend so much time when perhaps somebody has a better solution?

I know app2sd and link2sd, but I need to link all files, not just what the application sees. My internal memory is full and I have already app2sd installed. I need to free more space (for example, dalvik-cache). Unfortunately hardlink doesn't seem to work, so I need a better solution. When I softlink the cache, I can't install anything. The path seems to make a problem to Android.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My internal memory is full and I have already app2sd installed.  I need to free more space for example dalvik-cache.  Unfortunately hardlink doesn't seems to work so I need a better solution. When I softlink the cache I can't install anything.  The path seems to make a problem to android.

Comment: @Flow see his other question: [Why can't I create a hard link?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/48305/16575). Probably *Directory Bind* is what he needs, I mentioned it already over there.

Comment: Directory bind is only folder level. I need softlink to files.